# Efficient way to conditionally categorize across columns in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I'm trying to sort a data frame into categories. Similar to what you'd need for a Venn diagram, but I'd like to 'grepl' sample the column headers somehow. Meaning, as long as a pattern is shared and it satisfies the numeric threshold, it can be sorted into said category.

Example data:

```
df <- data.frame(a_b_c = c(1,3,5,0,0), a_b=c(0,0,4,0,0), a_b_c_d=c(1,2,2,3,0),
                 b_d=c(0,0,3,2,3), a_c = c(1,5,1,0,0))
df

>  a_b_c a_b a_b_c_d b_d a_c    
>     1   0       1   0   1     
>     3   0       2   0   5     
>     5   4       2   3   1   
>     0   0       3   2   0   
>     0   0       0   3   0
```

**Desired output**

```
df_final <- data.frame(df, category = c("Other", "Shared c", "Shared all", "Shared d", "Appears once"))

df_final

>  a_b_c a_b a_b_c_d b_d a_c     category
>     1   0       1   0   1        Other
>     3   0       2   0   5     Shared c
>     5   4       2   3   1   Shared all
>     0   0       3   2   0     Shared d
>     0   0       0   3   0 Appears once
```

I'm thinking it involves a tidy verse mutate statement with `case_when()` and/or `ifelse()` statements, but I cannot get the logic down correctly. This is an example test dataset, my actual data has >20 columns. So this is why I'd like to categorize the column headers with wild cards.

Open to any and all suggestions.

Comment: This seems to be grepping on the column *names*, not their values, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a "pivot", `case_when`, and "join" gets you your results.

```r
library(dplyr)
# library(tidyr) # pivot_longer

df <- data.frame(a_b_c = c(1,3,5,0,0), a_b=c(0,0,4,0,0), a_b_c_d=c(1,2,2,3,0),
                 b_d=c(0,0,3,2,3), a_c = c(1,5,1,0,0)) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number())

df %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarize(
    category = case_when(
      all(value > 0)                     ~ "Shared all",
      sum(value > 0) == 1L               ~ "Appears once",
      all(value == 0 | grepl("c", name)) ~ "Shared c",
      all(value == 0 | grepl("d", name)) ~ "Shared d",
      TRUE                               ~ "Other"
    )
  ) %>%
  left_join(df, ., by = "row")
#   a_b_c a_b a_b_c_d b_d a_c row     category
# 1     1   0       1   0   1   1     Shared c
# 2     3   0       2   0   5   2     Shared c
# 3     5   4       2   3   1   3   Shared all
# 4     0   0       3   2   0   4     Shared d
# 5     0   0       0   3   0   5 Appears Once
```

I have to add a `row` column in order to be confident the category will be paired back to the original row, since otherwise the rows are not uniquely identified (except by complete uniqueness, something I was not banking on). I `pivot`ed so that we do not rely on specific column names or the existence of precisely five columns (this works equally well with 3 and 300, give or take your logic rules. Lastly, the use of `!grepl(...) | value>0` is a specific inversion to ensure that all `c`-including (and `d`) names have a value above 0; it's easily extensible, though depending on your actual use-case you may need a stronger regex (e.g., word boundaries).

Comment: What if I needed to add a grepl statement that INCLUDES "a" & excludes "c"? Extending the grepl statement as you suggest - but need to specify exclusions (or value == 0) with another grepl().

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but perhaps something like `all( (grepl("a", name) & !grepl("c", name)) | value == 0)`.

Comment: Yes, this works. However, I'm not completely understanding how to modify the inversion (!grel()) to perform the other complicated "sorting" I'm working on. I'm continuing to play around with this and reading up on regex. 
I need to assign other categories like "Only appears with a_" and "Only appears with a_b".

Comment: Wondering if pivoting long to begin with and having additional columns as factors would be helpful. I'm sure there are several ways to approach this, but my data is presenting additional challenges on the way to getting there.

Comment: There are definitely benefits to both long and wide, but I think in this case pivoting up-front (as I've done here) *enables* different ways of looking at it. To your question of trying to figure out the regex, think this: if you start a regex with `all(value == 0 | ...)` then you're effectively saying "only consider those with non-zero value", which seems a little unintuitive until you realize that values of zero will never count *against* your other conditional. I edited the answer to adapt two lines to this methodology/pattern. I hope it clears things up.

Answer (score -1):

In `base R`, we can create a numeric index based on the logic, then use that index as position index for changing the values

```
i1 <- apply(df > 0, 1, function(x) {
      x1 <- x[x]
       c1 <- all(grepl('c', names(x1)))
       d1 <- all(grepl('d', names(x1)))
       all(x) + 2 * c1 + 4 * d1 +  8 * (length(x1) == 1)})
df$category <- c('Shared all', 'Shared c', 'Shared d',
            'Appears once', 'other')[as.integer(factor(i1))]
df$category
#[1] "Shared c"     "Shared c"     "Shared all"   "Shared d"     "Appears once"
```

Comment: Not sure why a base R solution is downvted